# Reactive forms - disabled attribute

Tags: angular, typescript

I am trying to use the `disabled` attribute from a `formControl`. When I put it in the template, it works:

```
<md-input formControlName="id" placeholder="ID" [disabled]="true"></md-input>
```

But the browser alerts me:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
>   directive. If you set disabled to true
>         when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
>         you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
>
> ```
>   Example: 
>   form = new FormGroup({
>     first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
>     last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
>   });
> ```

So I put it in the `FormControl`, and deleted from the template:

```
constructor(private itemsService: ItemsService) {
    this._items = [];
    this.myForm = new FormGroup({
        id: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
        title: new FormControl(),
        description: new FormControl()
    });
    this.id = this.myForm.controls['id'];
    this.title = this.myForm.controls['title'];
    this.description = this.myForm.controls['description'];
    this.id.patchValue(this._items.length);
}
```

But it does not work (it is not disabling the `input`). What is the problem?

Comment: This seems to work just fine with the current version of Angular 2:
http://plnkr.co/edit/CQQtkYC9D5EoH0sAlNCV?p=preview

Comment: I am using the lastest angular cli project for testing

Comment: You're using @angular/material, so, per their github issues: https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/1171

It's not yet supported and they're in alpha so you can't expect it to be feature complete.

Comment: Yes, it was the problem

Comment: You can try putting `this.myForm.controls['id'].disable()` somewhere in the constructor. I did a library which makes it easier to work with dynamic forms: https://github.com/mat3e/dorf

Comment: Whole point of using reactive form is minimalized code in template and functionalities to component.(including disable switching values validations etc...)
If you want to make use of disable, validation in template  way then we all should consider using template driven form approach

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53627002/8047091 this works for me. Thanks for help

Answer (score 199, accepted):

I have been using `[attr.disabled]` because I still like this template driven than programmatic enable()/disable() as it is superior IMO.

Change

```
<md-input formControlName="id" placeholder="ID" [disabled]="true"></md-input>
```

to

```
<md-input formControlName="id" placeholder="ID" [attr.disabled]="true"></md-input>
```

If you are on newer material change `md-input` to `mat-input`.

Comment: It works, thanks! But i don't understand why i should use "attr.disabled" (not only "disabled") ?

Comment: This also works for Telerik Kendo for Angular components. Some of them have `[disabled]` property and when using it I got the same compile warning. I have changed `[disabled]` to `[attr.disabled]` and it gets propagated into the component `.disabled` property.

Comment: Just to note, with [attr.disabled] you can't use bind it in two way. It only works once. With `[disabled]` and the warning in console is working. I'm using Angular 4.1.3

Comment: I think that `[attr.disabled]` just does not trigger the warning that `[disabled]` shows

Comment: Can you elaborate on why do you think it's "superior"?

Comment: Properties of form field are readable from the HTML template. Say one fine day you decide to look what disables a given field the instinct is to walk from HTML template towards the typescript code than the other ways.

Comment: For mat-checkbox this is still not working in v7 of angular. The only way is to set [disabled]=true and accept the console warning. The issue will only be a problem if the checkbox values changes during the state of the page, you will then have to handle this yourself.

Comment: This won't be updated with every dynamic change in the value used for the disabled attribute. Angular's change detection doesn't trigger with every update, will have to be manually done, if this has to work.

Comment: I don't think this work-around is valid anymore. It may work on the older Angular versions, but it emits a warning on mine (Angular 7.2.12).

Comment: This does not work on newer Angular versions. The `disabled` will be ignored

Comment: then it will be no more considered as a "reactive  form"

Comment: Not working in angular 9

Answer (score 62):

In my case with **Angular 8**. I wanted to toggle enable/disable of the input depending on the condition.

`[attr.disabled]` didn't work for me so here is my solution.

I removed `[attr.disabled]` from HTML and in the component function performed this check:

```
if (condition) {
    this.form.controls.myField.disable();
} else {
    this.form.controls.myField.enable();
}
```

Comment: It's disappointing to have to write code for this (which you could just do with one expression in template-driven) - but looks that's mostly what reactive forms is about..

Comment: This is my final way to go as `[attr.disabled]` does not work for me too

Answer (score 33):

You can enable/disable a form control by using the following methods:

control.disable() or control.enable()

If that did not work for you can use a directive

```
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  selector: '[disableControl]'
})
export class DisableControlDirective {

  @Input() set disableControl( condition : boolean ) {
    const action = condition ? 'disable' : 'enable';
    this.ngControl.control[action]();
  }

  constructor( private ngControl : NgControl ) {
  }

}
```

Then you could use it like this

```
<input [formControl]="formControl" [disableControl]="disable">
<button (click)="disable = true">Disable</button>
<button (click)="disable = false">Enable</button>
```

This technique is described here:

https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110

Hope it helps

Comment: can you please show some js code snippet how to do this

Comment: please provide any stackb samples

Comment: here is example: 
https://netbasal.com/disabling-form-controls-when-working-with-reactive-forms-in-angular-549dd7b42110

Comment: That doesn't work with Angular 8. It gives ```NgControl (`No provider for NgControl`)```

Comment: I can confirm that this solution doesn't work anymore as of Angular 8!!

Comment: To make this work you'll have to import the `ReactiveFormsModule` in your `@NgModule` which is used for view. As FormControl is exposed as a part of `ReactiveFormsModule` and NOT the `FormsModule`.

Comment: this should be the accepted answer. This is working in angular 8+, don't forget to import the directive in your module :)

Comment: I loved to use this solution, but it stopped working for me now that I updated my project from Angular 10.2 to 11.0 to 12.0. Has anyone experienced the same problem and got an idea why that is?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, that was a false alarm. I tried to use this solution in a new component and it didn't work. But the reason seems to be because I try to use it on a Material select. On my old input textfields it is still working, though.

Comment: Thanks for this! There are a few bugs with this directive, firstly the enabled or disabled state isn't initialised correctly when the directive is initialised (e.g. if the initial state of disableControl is false the control will still be enabled until it is changed once). Secondly, it changes the state of the control even if the control is in the desired state already making it sub-optimal performance.

Answer (score 30):

It needs a default value, even if it's an empty string. So this:

```
this.registerForm('someName', {
  firstName: new FormControl({disabled: true}),
});
```

...should be this:

```
this.registerForm('someName', {
  firstName: new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true}),
});
```

The reasoning behind this requirement can be found here: [github.com/angular/angular/pull/10994#issuecomment-244195999](https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/10994#issuecomment-244195999)

See my question (which I don't believe is a duplicate): [Passing 'disabled' in form state object to FormControl constructor doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49200258/passing-disabled-in-form-state-object-to-formcontrol-constructor-doesnt-work)

Comment: This is not working for mat-select form control. Do you know why is that?

Comment: You can disable individual mat-options as well, just with a [disabled] attribute in the option itself.

Comment: Angular throws a warning when you disabled the input in the template.

Comment: @elliottregan, this isn't disabling the input in the template, is it?

Comment: @BBaysinger No, you're right. That was in response to FunkMoney33

Answer (score 8):

```
this.form.disable()
this.form.enable()
```

For one formcontrol makes disable

```
this.form.get('first').disable()
this.form.get('first').enable()
```

Or initial set method.

```
first: new FormControl({disabled: true}, Validators.required)
```

Answer (score 5):

Initialization (component) using:

```
public selector = new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true});
```

Then instead of using (template):

```
<ngx-select
[multiple]="true"
[disabled]="errorSelector"
[(ngModel)]="ngxval_selector"
[items]="items"
</ngx-select>
```

Just remove the attribute disabled:

```
<ngx-select
[multiple]="true"
[(ngModel)]="ngxval_selector"
[items]="items"
</ngx-select>
```

And when you have items to show, launch (in component): `this.selector.enable();`

Answer (score 5):

**Only who are using reactive forms :** 
For native HTML elements [attr.disabled] will work but for  material elements we need to dynamically disable the element.

```
this.form.get('controlname').disable();
```

Otherwise it will show in console warning message.

Answer (score 3):

This was my solution:

```
this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    socDate: [[{ value: '', disabled: true }], Validators.required],
    ...
)}

<input fxFlex [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Select Date" formControlName="socDate" [attr.disabled]="true" />
```

Comment: Hi Frank, welcome to StackOverflow, and thanks for your answer!  While it is certainly great to provide a working soluition in code, it can help others now and in the future understand your answer better if you add a bit of explanation beyond the code.

Comment: My solution lik yours, but "input" element not need 'disabled'.It just like `this.myForm = this._formBuilder.group({
    socDate: [[{ value: '', disabled: true }], Validators.required],
    ...
)}` and it work well.

Answer (score 3):

I tried these in angular 7. It worked successfully.

```
this.form.controls['fromField'].reset();
if(condition){
      this.form.controls['fromField'].enable();
}
else{
      this.form.controls['fromField'].disable();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

When you create new Form control, use next:

```
variable: FormControl = new FormControl({value: '', disabled: true});
```

If you want change activity, use next:

```
this.variable.enable()
```

or

```
this.variable.disable()
```

Answer (score 2):

disabling of mat form fields is exempted if you are using form validation,so do make sure that your form field does not have any validations like(validators.required),this worked for me.
for ex:

editUserPhone: new FormControl({value:'  ',disabled:true})

this makes the phone numbers of user to be non editable.

Answer (score 2):

in **Angular-9** if you want to disable/enable on button click here is a simple solution if you are using reactive forms.

define a function in component.ts file

```
//enable example you can use the same approach for disable with .disable()

toggleEnable() {
  this.yourFormName.controls.formFieldName.enable();
  console.log("Clicked")
}
```

Call it from your component.html

*e.g*

```
<button type="button" data-toggle="form-control" class="bg-primary text-white btn- 
                reset" style="width:100%"(click)="toggleEnable()">
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Input('disableControlDirective') disableControlDirective;
   ngOnChanges(values) {
    if (values['disableControlDirective']) {
      const disableOrEnable = this.disableControlDirective ? 'disable' : 'enable';
      this.ngControl.control[disableOrEnable]();
    }
  }
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/60075989/14990860

Answer (score 1):

[Extending on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50741632/2023963) to fix a bug with the initial state of the control and performance of the directive.

Use the following directive in the template and pass in the disabled state using `[disableControl]="disabled"` on the form control in the template.

```js
import { Directive, Input, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

/**
 * Used to control form control disabled state from a template
 */
@Directive({
  // eslint-disable-next-line @angular-eslint/directive-selector
  selector: '[disableControl]',
})
export class DisableControlDirective implements OnInit {
  @Input() set disableControl(condition: boolean) {
    this._disableControl = condition;
    this._set();
  }
  private _disableControl: boolean;

  constructor(private ngControl: NgControl) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._set();
  }

  private _set() {
    const control = this.ngControl?.control;
    if (this._disableControl === true) {
      if (control && control.enabled) control.disable();
    } else {
      if (control && control.disabled) control.enable();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [attr.disabled] instead [disabled], in my case it works ok

Comment: While this might be possible, you should not use a template driven solution when working with reactive forms. The problem with mixing those two is that the reactive form state can no longer be trusted.

Comment: it uses to disable but if i set this as false also control get disable

Answer (score 0):

The beauty of reactive forms is you can catch values changes event of any input element very easily and at the same time you can change their values/ status. So here is the another way to tackle your problem by using `enable` `disable`.

Here is the complete solution on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-53925391?embed=1&file=app/app.component.ts).

Comment: I suggest you post the code here as well, or at least a snippet. I found this solution useful, so subscribing to the value change and triggering enable/disable seems a good option.

Answer (score 0):

You can proceed as follows to disable more than one control on a page.
You won't get the Reactive forms - disabled attribute error when you change the controls after creating them after page load.

```
this.formNextBonusGroup = NextTypePrim.asFormGroup();
 for (var control in this.formNextBonusGroup.controls) 
{
  if (this.detailInputVisible) 
  {
     this.formNextBonusGroup.get(control).disable();
  } else
  {
      this.formNextBonusGroup.get(control).enable();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't to `[attr.disabled]` or `[disabled]`, do this in your **controller**:

1. Add new method with body:

   ```
    changeDeactive() {
    if (yourCondition) {
        this.yourForm.controls.yourControl?.enable();
    } else {
        this.yourForm.controls.yourControl?.disable();
    }
   ```

   }
2. (Optionally) and the best way is to do it in a `subscription` (RxJS), that means to add a new subscription in the constructor (or `ngInit()` function), because your condition can change:

   ```
    ngOnInit() {
    // first approach:  
    this.yourForm.controls.yourControl?.valueChanges.subscribe(() => {
        this.changeDeactive();
    });

    //or this:         
    this.yourForm.get('yourControl').valueChanges
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.changeDeactive();
        });
   ```

   }

Answer (score -1):

add disable="true" to html field 
Example :disable

```
<amexio-text-input formControlName="LastName" disable="true" [(ngModel)]="emplpoyeeRegistration.lastName" [field-label]="'Last Name'" [place-holder]="'Please enter last name'" [allow-blank]="true" [error-msg]="'errorMsg'" [enable-popover]="true" [min-length]="2"
[min-error-msg]="'Minimum 2 char allowed'" [max-error-msg]="'Maximum 20 char allowed'" name="xyz" [max-length]="20">
[icon-feedback]="true">
</amexio-text-input>
```

Comment: Not working . sample link - https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zdpavf?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: This answer will not work in reavtive form.this is related to template driven form

Answer (score -2):

add name attribute to your md-input. if it doesn't solve the problem, please post your template

Answer (score -6):

It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

Example:

```
form = new `FormGroup`({
    first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
    last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
});
```

Comment: You literally just pasted in the error message and code sample that he included in the original question. This is not helpful.

Answer (score -8):

Ultimate way to do this.

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.interPretationForm.controls.InterpretationType.valueChanges.takeWhile(()=> this.alive).subscribe(val =>{
    console.log(val); // You check code. it will be executed every time value change.
  })
}
```