# Warning while disabling the input component

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-forms

I am using **select** and **input** components in the same line.Here i have made **input** field active only after selecting something from **select** component as shown in below image.

[image]

Below is the code.

**HTML**

```
      <mat-form-field class="id-name">
         <mat-select placeholder="ID Card" (ngModelChange)="onChange($event)" formControlName="IdProof">
            <mat-option *ngFor="let id of  idProofs" [value]="id.value">
                {{id.viewValue}}
            </mat-option>
         </mat-select>
      </mat-form-field>

      <mat-form-field class="id-number">
        <input formControlName="idNum" matInput required>
        <mat-error *ngIf="editStaffForm.get('idNum').invalid && (editStaffForm.get('idNum').dirty || editStaffForm.get('idNum').touched)">
          Please enter id card number
        </mat-error>
      </mat-form-field>
```

**TS**

```
  public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.editStaffForm = this.fb.group({
        IdProof: null,
        idNum: [null, [Validators.required]],
     });
   this.onChange(0);
   }

   public onChange(data: any): void {
     if (data) {
      this.editStaffForm.get('idNum').enable();
        } 
     else {
      this.editStaffForm.get('idNum').disable();
        }
   }
```

Here i am getting this warning in the browser console.

```
      It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form 
       directive. If you set disabled to true
         when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled 
      attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
      you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' 
        errors.

     Example: 
          form = new FormGroup({
             first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, 
                Validators.required),
               last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
            });
```

I know this is the duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494968/reactive-forms-disabled-attribute),but the answers given for this question doesn't worked for me.

Comment: If it's not showing in StackBlitz then the error you're seeing is happening in a different place than what you're showing us.

Comment: May be something wrong in my code.

Comment: create the form disabled at first and don't call to onChange(0). NOTE: I think that if you want to call the function with a null argument -not in ngOnInit-, you must write onChange(null) -not onChange(0).

Comment: Okay let me try.

Comment: It's working fine.Thank you so much.@Eliseo

Comment: Can you explain why `onChange(null)` not `onChange(0)` when i call it inside `ngOnInit`??

Comment: I supouse your data is any (in general an object). If is a number, obviously you must use 0. There are no diference in if (!variable) is your variable equals: 0, null, undefined or "". Just sugest use null because I think your function, in general expect an object type {prop1="value1",prop2="value2} else forget it