# unable to disable matInput in angular form

Tags: angular

I have a form and i want to disable one of my inputs on a condition.

```
<mat-form-field>
    <input matInput formControlName="domain" [disabled]="!is_staff && recipients[selectedIndex].verified">
</mat-form-field>
```

As you can see I want that whenever condition `!is_staff && recipients[selectedIndex].verified` happened, input be disabled.

But disable attribute is not working!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494968/reactive-forms-disabled-attribute

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When it comes to reactive forms, it is not a good practice to disabled FormControls by directly manipulating the DOM. What you did on your code will essentially result in the following warning:

> It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form
>   directive. If you set disabled to true
>         when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
>         you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.
>
> ```
>   Example: 
>   form = new FormGroup({
>     first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
>     last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
>   });
> ```

Instead, you should be using the `disabled` property, as [defined](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disabled) by the AbstractControl class. This is what you should be doing:

```
this.yourForm = this.fb.group({
    domain: [{value: null, disabled: !this.is_staff && this.recipients[selectedIndex].verified},
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is another way to disable a field. 
Get the particular form's control, and then invoke the disable().

For example: `this.form.control.first_name.disable()`