# Angular 9 dynamically disable form control

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

What I'm trying to achive is after initiation of the form to disable some controls;

```
this.someForm= this._fb.group({
  lastName: ['', Validators.required],
  firstName: ['', Validators.required]
});

<input type="text" formControlName="firstName" class="input-field"/>

this.someForm.controls.firstName.disable(); //not works
this.someForm.get('firstName').disable(); //not works
```

Is there a way to do that without recreating form?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494968/reactive-forms-disabled-attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.someForm.get('firstName').disable(); //not works
```

should work, you just need to update value and validity afterwards:

```
this.someForm.get('firstName').updateValueAndValidity();
```