# Disable not working when using formControlName and working fine when using [formControl]

Tags: angular, forms

Disable functionality is not working properly when we use FormcontrolName instead of Formcontrol in html,
below is the sample code.

Below is .ts file

```
ngOnInit() {
this.CreateUserRoleForm();
}

CreateUserRoleForm(){
this.employeeForm = new FormGroup({
  firstName: new FormControl(),
  MiddleName: new FormControl(),
  LastName: new FormControl(),
  isActive: new FormControl(),
  isEligible: new FormControl()
});
}

FetchUserAccess() {   
this.validateUserRoleForm('enableformcontrols')    
this._userinfoService.GetUserAccess().subscribe(res => {                
        this.validateUserRoleForm('disableFormcontrols');                                   
});
}


 validateUserRoleForm(actionType: string) {
 if (actionType == 'enableformcontrols') {
    this.employeeForm.get('firstName').enable();
    this.employeeForm.get('MiddleName').enable();
    this.employeeForm.get('LastName').enable();
    this.employeeForm.controls["isActive"].enable();
    this.employeeForm.controls["isEligible"].enable();
  }  

 else if (actionType == 'disableFormcontrols') {
    this.employeeForm.get('firstName').disable();
    this.employeeForm.get('MiddleName').disable();
    this.employeeForm.get('LastName').disable();
    this.employeeForm.controls["isActive"].disable();
    this.employeeForm.controls["isEligible"].disable();
  }  
}
```

.html file:

```
<div>
<form [formGroup]="employeeForm">      
  <div>
    <div class="modal-content">        
      <div class="modal-body">          
        <div class="row mt-2">              
          <div class="col-auto my-auto">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="pa-checkbox">
                <label class="form-label strong">
                  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isActive">
                  <span style="margin-right:10px">isActive</span>
                </label>
              </div>
              <div class="pa-checkbox">
                <label class="form-label strong">
                  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="isEligible">
                  <span style="margin-right:10px">isEligible</span>
                </label>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-auto my-auto">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" (click)="FetchUserAccess()">Fetch 
Access </button>
          </div>
        </div>           
      </div>         
    </div>
  </div>  
</form>
 </div>
```

If i use formControlName disable functionality is not working while trying to disable

but if use  below Formcontrol its working fine:

```
[formControl]="employeeForm.controls.isActive"

[formControl]="employeeForm.controls.isEligible"
```

So how does the formcontrol properties differ when we use formControl and formControlName

Comment: it's the same you use `[formControl]="employeeForm.get('isActive')"` or `formControlName="isActive"`, but is you want disable or enable a control, I suggest use a directive, see this SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494968/reactive-forms-disabled-attribute. Using a directive you can use some like `[disableControl]="!employeeForm.get('isActive').value"`

Comment: Thank u..it worked fine after using    setTimeout(() => {}) inside validateUserRoleForm method.