# Remove waring message from console

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

It looks like you're using the disabled attribute with a reactive form directive. If you set disabled to true
when you set up this control in your component class, the disabled attribute will actually be set in the DOM for
you. We recommend using this approach to avoid 'changed after checked' errors.

```
 form = new FormGroup({
first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
```

});

Example:
form = new `FormGroup`({
first: new FormControl({value: 'Nancy', disabled: true}, Validators.required),
last: new FormControl('Drew', Validators.required)
});`enter code here`

Comment: Is this supposed to be an answer?

Comment: Rereading this, I think I understand the question, although it doesn't really follow the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guidelines. It sounds like you've put a `disabled` attribute on the HTML element for a `FormControl`. Remove it and use `FormControl.disable()` instead.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it just is a verbatim copy of the angular warning from the console, but with botched formatting. And the question has been asked and answered 6 years ago: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40494968/reactive-forms-disabled-attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply go around this problem and use `[readonly]` on your attribute.

Working example:

```
<input formControlName="disabledInput" [disabled]="ifSomething()"> // throws warning
```

```
<input formControlName="disabledInput" [readonly]="ifSomething()">//works the same with no warning
```

Comment: You might also want to add `[attr.inert]="ifSomething() || null`, (see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73112762/how-do-i-use-inert-in-angular-14) because otherwise clicking into a readonly input and away again marks it as `touched` and might cause validation messages to show up.