# How do I use "inert" in Angular 14?

Tags: angular, html-inert

I would like to use the new `inert` attribute in my Angular 14 app.

How do I use this attribute?

I've tried the following

`<div [attr.inert]="someBoolean"></div>`

But `inert="false"` is ending up in my HTML. This is making the element inert, even when I don't want it to be.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Since `inert` is a boolean value, its presence means "it's on". Setting `inert="false"` still means true. The only way to remove the inert behavior, is to remove that attribute from the DOM element entirely.

In Angular, it does not have a deep semantic understanding of which attributes are boolean ones, which are strings, etc. When the value is null or undefined for *any* attribute, Angular removes it.

The solution is to do the following:

`[attr.inert]="someBoolean ? '' : null"`

Which will then insert `inert` when the boolean is true, and `null` when false, resulting in Angular removing the inert attribute

Comment: or `[attr.inert]="someBoolean || null"` for brevity